# Adding +1 day at date array function in PHP

Tags: php

My current function looks like this:

```
        function getThisDayAsArray() {
        return array(
            "y" => date("Y", $this->properDateTS),
            "m" => date("m", $this->properDateTS),
            "d" => date("d", $this->properDateTS)
        );

    }
```

and it works fine for returning the correct date.
I am trying to have it returning always +1 day from the currenty one.

```
$date = new DateTime('+1 day');
```

fails for me.
Any suggestions?

Comment: $date = new DateTime('+1 days')

Comment: Thanks. Turned out to be a typo.

Comment: @Osama why not make your comment an answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The right syntax to add a day to the date object is

```
$date = new DateTime('+1 days')
```